# prevent default_url_options from being called and add paramters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've default_url_options that set locale like that

```
  def default_url_options
      {
        locale: I18n.locale,

      }
  end
```

but in one case I want to `redirect_to something_url` without adding ?`locale=en`

currently direct_to something automatically add locale like this http://localhost/something?locale=en
I want to remove the locale params

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent adding default url options by explicitly setting them to `nil` in the url helper:

```
redirect_to something_url(locale: nil)
```

Comment: Best solution :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Provided that `en` is the default locale you can do:

```
def default_url_options
  {}.tap do |options|
    if I18n.locale != I18n.default_locale 
      options[:locale] = I18n.locale 
    end
  end 
end
```

Comment: can you explain more how this help. 
I want to  NOT automatically add locale=en in one case but I want to always add locale=en in all other cases

Comment: This would solve the problem if you don't want the locale param added for the the default locale.

Answer (score 0):

In above snippet simply add,

```
def default_url_options
   I18n.locale = (url == something_url) ? nil  : I18n.default_locale
   {
    locale: I18n.locale
    }
end
```

here url and something_url you need to add as per your application.

Hope this will work in your case.

Comment: This is not an optimal solution as you will need to add more condition for each url

Comment: Yeah right. But you mentioned only for one URL, so.